# Discovery Instances using eureka-js-client node library

Tags: node.js, netflix-eureka

I am using the eureka-js-client for discovery.

When using the methods provided to discover, I am getting the following output.

How should we parse this to discover URLs that can be used by the calling program. Should we use the hostName field from JSON output and use it. Lack of info on how to use. Appreciate any help.

Code:

```
    client.start((error) => {
  console.log(error || 'complete');
      if(!error){
          //Get Instances By App ID
      // appInfo.application.instance contains array of instances 
      var appInfo = client.getInstancesByAppId('security-api');
      console.log('appInfo:' + appInfo);
      console.log('appInfo:' + JSON.stringify(appInfo));
      console.log('appInfo instances:' + JSON.stringify(appInfo.application));
      //Get Instances By Vip Address
      // appInfo.application.instance contains array of instances 
      // var appInfo2 = client.getInstancesByVipAddress('security-api-client');
      // console.log('appInfo2:' + appInfo2);
  }
});
```

Output example:

```
   [  
   {  
      "hostName":"security-api.mybluemix.net",
      "app":"SECURITY-API",
      "ipAddr":"127.0.0.1",
      "status":"UP",
      "overriddenstatus":"UNKNOWN",
      "port":{  
         "$":62114,
         "@enabled":"true"
      },
      "securePort":{  
         "$":7002,
         "@enabled":"false"
      },
      "countryId":1,
      "dataCenterInfo":{  
         "@class":"com.netflix.appinfo.InstanceInfo$DefaultDataCenterInfo",
         "name":"MyOwn"
      },
      "leaseInfo":{  
         "renewalIntervalInSecs":30,
         "durationInSecs":90,
         "registrationTimestamp":1479240207261,
         "lastRenewalTimestamp":1479240357280,
         "evictionTimestamp":0,
         "serviceUpTimestamp":1479168100962
      },
      "metadata":{  
         "@class":"java.util.Collections$EmptyMap"
      },
      "statusPageUrl":"http://security-api.mybluemix.net/info",
      "vipAddress":"security-api-client",
      "isCoordinatingDiscoveryServer":"false",
      "lastUpdatedTimestamp":"1479240207261",
      "lastDirtyTimestamp":"1479240207201",
      "actionType":"ADDED"
   }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your specific requirements, but most commonly you will want to take the `hostName` and the `port` (or the `securePort`) and build the URL in your application code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be the same that I had and solved here [Spring Cloud Netflix Eureka doesn't find eureka-js instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50965591/spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-doesnt-find-eureka-js-instances/50968693#50968693)

Missed `instanceId` field in new Eureka object.

Wasn't mentioned in eureka-js-client doc